# e mail content categorization

Tags: c, email-headers

I want to separate subject content of an email into one text file,other header fields into next text file ,finally the message body into another text file.My code can extract email fields having single line content.but it doesn't extract if the field has more than one line.(This is required because fields such as Subject,To ans so on may have multiple lines.)  plz help me...
My code is given below:

program name:f2all.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 5) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input. Usage: %s input_file output_file\n",
             argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *ifp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *ofp1 = fopen(argv[2],"w");/*this points to a file(eg:f.txt),which should contain`contents of subject field only*/
    FILE *ofp2= fopen(argv[3],"w");/*this points to a file(eg:g.txt),which should contain contents of all other other header  field only*/
    FILE *ofp3= fopen(argv[4],"w");/*this points to a file(eg:h.txt),which should contain contents of message body only*/

    char *buf = NULL;  
    char *buf1 = NULL;   /* forces getline to allocate space for buf */
    ssize_t read = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    char *ptr = NULL;

    if (ifp==NULL)    
    {    
        printf("\nFile cannot be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while ((read = getline (&buf, &n, ifp)) != -1)
        {
            if (((ptr=strstr(buf,"Subject:")) != 0))
            {
                fprintf(ofp1,"%s",(ptr+8));      /* use (ptr + 8) to trim 'Subject:` away */
            }
            if ((ptr=strstr(buf,"subject :")) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(ofp1,"%s",(ptr+9));         
            }

            if (((ptr=strstr(buf,"Date:")) != 0)||((ptr=strstr(buf,"From:")) != 0)||((ptr=strstr(buf,"X-cc:")) != 0))
            {
                fprintf(ofp2,"%s",(ptr+5));         
            }
            if ((ptr=strstr(buf,"X-To:")) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(ofp2,"%s",(ptr+5));                 
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(buf1,buf);
                fprintf(ofp1,"%s",buf1);  

            }   
        }
    }
    if (buf)        /* free memory allocated by getline for buf */
        free (buf);
    fclose(ofp1);
    fclose(ofp2);
    fclose(ofp3);
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

I did compilation and then run the program as follows:

princy@PRINCY:~/minipjt/SUBJECT$ cc f2all.c
f2all.c: In function ‘main’:
f2all.c:85:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
princy@PRINCY:~/minipjt/SUBJECT$ ./a.out 8.txt f.txt g.txt h.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to use `free()`

Comment: `buf1` is never allocated but you call `strcpy(buf1, buf);`

Answer (score 0):

You can establish a context when scanning through a file and then print to the output fle according to that context. Otherwise, your conditions will only hold for the first line of each header entry.

In that light, it makes sense to keep an array of output file pointers.

Your code strips the keyword from the header entries. This means that the context will be lost when reading the output file: Is `xy@example.com` the sender, the recipient or the preferred address for replies?

Example implementation based on yours below.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    SUBJECT,
    HEADER,
    BODY,
    NONE = -1
};

/*
 *      Check whether the line starts with any of the given keywords in
 *      kw. If so, return a pointer to the char after the colon. If not,
 *      return NULL. The array kw must be terminated with NULL.
 */
const char *is_header(const char *line, const char **kw)
{
    while (*kw) {
        int l = strlen(*kw);

        if (strncmp(line, *kw, l) == 0 && line[l] == ':') {
            /* Note: Could use strncasecmp here for case-insenitive matching */
            return line + l + 1;
        }
        kw++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

const char *header_subject[] = { 
    "Subject", NULL
};

const char *header_other[] = { 
    "From", "To", "Date", /* ... */ NULL
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 5) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Error: insufficient input. Usage: %s input_file output_file\n",
            argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *ifp;
    FILE *ofp[3];

    ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    ofp[0] = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    ofp[1] = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    ofp[2] = fopen(argv[4], "w");

    /* Omitted: Error checking for file opening / creatinon */

    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t n;
    int context = NONE;

    while (getline(&buf, &n, ifp) != -1) {
        const char *line = buf;

        if (context != BODY) {
            /* Check for context if we are not already in the body */
            const char *p;

            /* Strip white space from string */
            while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t') line++;

            if (*line == '\n' || *line == '\r') {                
                context = BODY;     /* An empty line starts the body ... */ 
                continue;           /* ... but we don't print it. */
            }

            p = is_header(buf, header_subject);
            if (p) {
                line = p;
                while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t') line++;
                context = SUBJECT;
            }

            p = is_header(buf, header_other);
            if (p) {
                line = p;
                while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t') line++;
                context = HEADER;
            }
        }

        if (context != NONE) fprintf(ofp[context], "%s", line);
    }

    if (buf) free(buf);
    fclose(ofp[0]);
    fclose(ofp[1]);
    fclose(ofp[2]);
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```